# Dynamic type resolution - multiple calls to Type.GetType or scanning all types in assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, system.reflection, type-resolution

I am currently implementing a type name resolution scheme. The available information is very similar to what you would get in a regular C# source project:

- a list of `Assembly` references
- a list of `using` namespaces

At runtime, for each type name to resolve, the name is either fully qualified (with namespace, but not with assembly name) or it is a simple name that is expected to come from one of the `using` namespaces.

In order to find the `Type` matching each identifier, I am considering one of two strategies:

1. Preload all assemblies using `Assembly.Load` and scan all types. All simple names that have a namespace prefix matching one of the `using` namespaces will be precached. Also a dictionary is created mapping each namespace qualified type name in the assembly directly to its `Type`. Conflict resolution will be performed accordingly during the loading phase.
2. Do not preload anything. Whenever a type name arrives, try the following sequence:

   - Assume the name is fully qualified; concatenate each of the referenced assembly names in turn to create an assembly-qualified name and call `Type.GetType` to see if we get a valid type.
   - If the above step does not produce any valid type and the name has no prefix, assume it is a simple name; repeat the above step but each time prepend the simple name with one of the `using` namespaces to see if we get a valid type.

Which approach would be preferable and what are the pros and cons?

It is unclear at the moment how many types will need to be resolved in this way for every run but I'm assuming anything between 10 and 100. Multiple assemblies can be referenced at any point, each with potentially hundreds of types.

I am interested in knowing the relative performances of both strategies and curious to hear about existing best practices to deal with this scenario. In addition to performance, it would be very helpful to understand any difference in behavior side-effects: for instance, does scanning all types in an `Assembly` execute all the static constructors for loaded types? I would prefer an approach that would be as lazy as possible in running any code from referenced assemblies.

Comment: I believe that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It would be more useful if you would explain what you're trying to achieve with this, because maybe you're trying to re-invent the square wheel. Or who knows. Tell us which is the requirement behind your issue.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I am considering dynamic type resolution strategies for a scripting language and would like to be more comfortable with possible strategies for mapping names to types and their implications. By no means did I want to imply that I had a solution to the problem, but I did want to list the approaches that came to my mind. Would be great to learn of any other possibilities.

Comment: Are you creating an scripting language?

Comment: Yes, that is currently the case.

Comment: Uhm, an scripting language should be implemented using the Dynamic Language Runtime. Are you trying to implement one using regular CLR?

Comment: I am using the classes in the ```Expressions``` namespace to map my language constructs to CLR code. I do not intend the language to be a dynamic language. Generated constructs will be JIT compiled into fully typed dynamic methods.

Comment: Did you take a look at Irony? https://irony.codeplex.com/ It's not maintained anymore (or I think so...)

Comment: I was not aware of Irony. I like the monadic parser approach, but this seems to be more about generating an AST, rather than performing type resolution. Don't get me wrong, really very grateful for the resource, but it may be a bit out of scope for the question?

Comment: Well, that's why I pointed that maybe it's an XY problem. Maybe you're trying to do something from the scratch while there's some toolkit to do what you want. Or who knows...

Comment: BTW, are you creating some scripting language to learn how to do so, or is it something that you need for some business requirement, or you just want to create a new scripting language on top of .NET CLR?

Comment: Thanks, will take a closer look at Irony. In any case, I would still like to learn more about the original question. Currently I am mostly experimenting what can be easily achieved by lightweight scripting directly on top of expresson trees, rather than using DLR or using more heavy-duty arsenal like Roslyn.

Comment: No problem. Now I need to go to bed. BTW, this `Assembly` method should be useful in your case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new .NET Standard it turns out there is a much better way to do it, by using the new [`System.Reflection.Metadata`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/) namespace. In their own words:

> "This packages provides a low-level .NET (ECMA-335) metadata reader.
>
> It's geared for performance and is the ideal choice for building
>   higher-level libraries that intend to provide their own object model,
>   such as compilers."

Here's a small code snippet for listing the name and namespace for all type definitions in a given assembly file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

namespace MetadataTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(args[0]))
            using (var peFile = new PEReader(stream))
            {
                var metadataReader = peFile.GetMetadataReader();
                foreach (var type in metadataReader.TypeDefinitions)
                {
                    var definition = metadataReader.GetTypeDefinition(type);
                    var name = metadataReader.GetString(definition.Name);
                    var ns = metadataReader.GetString(definition.Namespace);
                    Console.WriteLine(ns + "." + name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```